# Google query or formula to find missing monthly fee

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, transpose, flatten

I am trying to build the below dashboard from the data given in the below format in the google sheet..

I can calculate the running balance but it is not helping me to figure out the missing fee months.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w5T36fk05Pw-0ARkxKUynrn5cUwfuWCEZ1lBt6UolZA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(TRIM({
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6=0, F3:H3&",", )),,9^9)), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6<>0, F3:H3&",", )),,9^9))}), ",$", ), I4:I6})
```

[image]

---

### update 1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(TRIM({
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6=0, F3:H3&",", )),,9^9)), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6<>0, F3:H3&",", )),,9^9))}), ",$", ), LEN(REGEXREPLACE({
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6<>0, ",", )),,9^9)), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6=0, ",", )),,9^9))}, "\s", ))*E4:E6, I4:I6})
```

[image]

---

### update 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(TRIM({
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6=0, F3:H3&",", )),,9^9)), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(F4:H6<>0, F3:H3&",", )),,9^9))}), ",$", ), 
 MMULT(F4:H6*1, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F3:H3))^0), I4:I6-
 MMULT(F4:H6*1, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F3:H3))^0), I4:I6})
```

---

### update 3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({REGEXREPLACE(TRIM({
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((F4:H6=0)*(REGEXMATCH(F3:H3, "Feb|Apr|May")), F3:H3&",", )),,9^9)), 
 FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF((F4:H6<>0)*(REGEXMATCH(F3:H3, "Feb|Apr|May")), F3:H3&",", )),,9^9))}), ",$", ), 
 MMULT((F4:H6)*(REGEXMATCH(F3:H3, "Feb|Apr|May")), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F3:H3))^0), I4:I6-
 MMULT((F4:H6)*(REGEXMATCH(F3:H3, "Feb|Apr|May")), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(F3:H3))^0), I4:I6})
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your help, it is working, a little more help is required, anyway can I dynamically define the monthly range to toggle between the months

Comment: The query is great, it would be a great help if we can add the Total Due months and Paid months amount into the query result.

Comment: @SameerFarooqui edit your sheet and include example of desired result

Comment: updated the sheet with required result

Comment: @SameerFarooqui answer updated

Comment: I have checked it is multiplying the monthly fee * header, I am looking to calculate the total amount based on input, sorry I forgot to mention the input value thing

Comment: @SameerFarooqui answer updated

Comment: its giving error if any input value is blank, (Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 3. Actual: 1.)

Comment: @SameerFarooqui fixed, try now

Comment: Works like a charm, also is there anyway to define the required range from other column, supposed if we need data from Jan to march, we will select the headers in other columns and the query gives us the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238712/discussion-between-sameer-farooqui-and-player0).

Comment: @SameerFarooqui answer updated with example of selected months

Comment: It is working as you described, what I meant, can we put a month filter somewhere else to filter the required result based on months, I have updated the sample sheet with example, let me know your thoughts

Comment: not rly sure if I understand what exactly you are after... if you want to reference months from cells you can do it like this where you type chosen months into red cells:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZtTF.png

Comment: exactly what I needed, thanks appreciate your help